# Ambiguous tags: how to proceed in general?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

Consider - for example - the tag [adhoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adhoc)

This tag currently has the following description:

> a solution designed for a specific problem or task, non-generalizable, and not intended to be able to be adapted to other purposes

However, a large part of the post are about iOS "Ad Hoc" provisioning ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4)).

There are several options in such a case:

1. make a new tag for iOS (e.g. [adhoc-ios](/questions/tagged/adhoc-ios))
2. make a new tag for the other posts (e.g. [adhoc-solution](/questions/tagged/adhoc-solution))
3. make new tags for both 1. and 2. so there is never any confusion (maybe also delete the confusing tag?)
4. don't change anything and allow the duplicate meaning

How do you know which option to pick when?
And then consequentially: are old questions supposed to be edited so they use the new tag?

Please note that I am looking for a general approach to find a solution and not a specific solution for the [adhoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adhoc).

Comment: Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/how-should-ambiguous-tags-be-dealt-with. In short, ambiguous tags are handled via a meta discussion on a case-by-case basis, but typically the ambiguous tag would be manually split up into two or more tags. Presumably the name for those new tags would be part of the meta discussion.

Comment: So there isn't a cookie-cutter solution... but shouldn't there be a guideline for a good approach to this problem?

Comment: I think until there is another distinct tag for ios adhoc issues, you may add the actual **iOS** tag in your question (at the end) which is also a good habit imho when asking question. That show right after reading the question you are not talking of something else than iOS adhoc.

Comment: Should I remove this question as it is more of a meta stackexchange discussion than a stackoverflow one?